# How to save tensorflow models in RAMDisk?

Tags: tensorflow, ramdisk

In my original python code, there is a frequent restore of the `ckpt` model file. It takes too much time to read the checkpoints again and again. So I decided to save the model in the memory. A simple way is to create a `RAMDisk` and save the model in that disk. However, something unexpected happens.

I deployed 1G of `RAMDisk` according to the tutorial [How to Create RAM Disk in Windows 10 for Super-Fast Read and Write Speeds](https://beebom.com/create-ram-disk-windows-10-super-fast-read-write-speeds/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20Create%20a%20RAM%20Disk%20in%20Windows,Prevent%20RAM%20Disk%20Data%20Loss%20Following%20Every%20Shutdown). My system is windows 11.

I made two attempts: In the first one, I copied my code to the RAMDisk E: and used `tf.train.Saver().save(self.sess,'./')` to save the model, but it reports that UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb4 in position 114: invalid start byte. However, if I put the code on other normal folders, it runs successfully.

In the second attempt, I put the code under D: and modified the line as `tf.train.Saver().save(self.sess,'E:\\')`, and it reports that cannot create directory E: Permission Denied. Obviously, E:\ is not a directory to create. So I don't know how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Your jupyter/python environment cannot go beyond the directory from which jupyter/python is started from and that's why you get a permission denied error.

However, you can run shell commands from the jupyter notebook. If your user has write access to your destination, you can do the following.

```py
model.save("my_model") # This will save the model to the current directory.
!mv "my_model" "E:\my_model" # This will move the model from the current directory to your required directory.
```

On a side note, I when searching for `tf.train.Saver().save()`, I get [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/Saver) page as the only relevant result, which says it is used for saving checkpoints and not model. Also they recommend switching to the newer `tf.train.Checkpoint` or `tf.keras.Model.save_weights`. None the less, the above method should work as expected.